# plane to torus projection

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am struggling to find a way to make a projection of a 2d plane $(x,y)$ onto a section of a torus. Is there a function $f$ that would map it depending on the given tor radii, the radii of its section and angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ ?

Torus mapping Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it by simply mapping the x interval of the plane to the interval [0,$\phi$] and the y interval to [0,$\theta$], then applying the torus parametrisation.

$x_{torus}$ = $(R1 + R2*cos(y))*cos(x)$

$y_{torus}$ = $(R1 + R2*cos(y))*sin(x)$

$z_{torus}$ = $R2*sin(y)$

with $R1,R2$ the radius of the torus and it's section respectively.